# Find and replace variables with SED in a file

Tags: sed, ksh

I'd would like to find and replace variables in a conf file in KSH (with SED).
My question is: what is the correct regex pattern to identify KSH variables (like $toto or ${toto}), by taking into account that variable's name can contains special characters ?

Here is an example:

Let's say I have `var_1=value1` and `var_2=value2` in my current shell (grepable in export -p).

The configuration file before find and replace

```
PARAM1=$var_1/tata.txt
PARAM2=${var_2}/tata.txt
```

The configuration file after find and replace

```
PARAM1=value1/tata.txt
PARAM2=value2/tata.txt
```

What I have to do:

1. Find $var_1 and ${var_2} in then conf file (with generic regex, I suppose I don't know if there are variables in the conf file)
2. Search value of each with *export -p | grep var_1* and *export -p | grep var_2*
3. Replace these 2 variables in conf file by the value found by previous search

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Provide an example of input file and your expected output.

Comment: @anubhava: Here is an example (directly in the post)

Answer (score 1):

This is one those cases where the *evil* and *dangerous* `eval` would come in handy:

```
while read line; do
  eval echo "$line"
done < inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: Interesting but I need to check for each variable if it exists in export -p (for error handling)

Comment: @pfevrier I'm not sure if I understand you correct, but if you want the shell to prompt you upon trying to substitute an undefined variable, you can say: `( set -u ; while read line; do eval echo "$line"; done < inputfile > outputfile )`.  This would give an error if a variable is undefined.

Comment: I do not know this option, maybe it's the solution. I'm going to test it :)

Comment: does not limit to variable substitution for example $(( $var_1 + $var_2 )) will execute the sum ant this is maybe not wanted

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` (I do see you are asking for `sed`)

```
awk '{gsub(/\${?var_1}?/,x);gsub(/\${?var_2}?/,y)}1' x="$var_1" y="$var_2" file
PARAM1=value1/tata.txt
PARAM2=value2/tata.txt
```

Comment: Thanks but I suppose I don't know the name of variables in conf file (I need something more generic)

Comment: Then you need a bash script that run a command for every variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Src=/tmp/sed.Source
FIn=/tmp/sed.In
FOut=/tmp/sed.Out

# take all variable as source but could be reduce (highly recommended)
set > ${Src}

cp YourFile ${FIn}
sed 's/=/ /' ${Src} | while read vName vValue
 do
   sed "s/\$$vName/$vValue/g;s/\${$vName}/$vValue/g" ${FIn} > ${FOut}
   mv ${Fout} ${FIn}
 done

#rm ${Src}
cat ${Fin}
#rm ${Fin}
```

Main concern is when content (value) of the variable contain regex specail char like /.* so not the best solution for that

could be done in sed only wit a preload of variable value and a marker than recursive replacement

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one-liner workaround:

```
cat config
PARAM1=$var_1/tata.txt
PARAM2=${var_2}/tata.txt

( export var_1=value1; export var_2=value2; bash -x ./config 2>&1 >/dev/null|sed 's/^+ //' )
PARAM1=value1/tata.txt
PARAM2=value2/tata.txt
```