# Run through file and parse placeholder variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, debian

I have been going over this for a few days and I am completely stuck. I put placeholder variables in my files which are in the following format: *$PLACEHOLDER_VAR* with the original variable being *$VAR*.

**Original config.conf**

```
TEST="$PLACEHOLDER_USERNAME"
TEST2="$PLACEHOLDER_PASSWORD"
```

What I want to do is have a deploy.sh which contains defined variables, and can run a command which will replace any placeholder variables with the defined variables, leaving it like this:

**New config.conf**

```
TEST="Tom"
TEST2="abc123"
```

I need a single command for my deploy.sh which will work for any placeholder variables.

**$PLACEHOLDER_USERNAME -> $USERNAME -> Tom**

An example (but not right) deploy.sh using username as an example

```
USERNAME="Tom"
PASSWORD="abc123"
FILE="config.conf"
sed -i s/STRING_TO_REPLACE/STRING_TO_REPLACE_IT/g $FILE
```

Can anyone please help me complete this script?

Comment: Same kind of question (and answer) as this other one: [Find and replace variables with SED in a file][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097241/find-and-replace-variables-with-sed-in-a-file/20099326

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this :

```
USERNAME="Tom"
PASSWORD="abc123"
FILE="config.conf"
sed -i "s/\$PLACEHOLDER_USERNAME/$USERNAME/g" $FILE
sed -i "s/\$PLACEHOLDER_PASSWORD/$PASSWORD/g" $FILE
# perl -p -i -e "s/\$PLACEHOLDER_PASSWORD/$PASSWORD/g" $FILE
```

I have also included a sample of the perl alternative to sed since im not sure if the sed above will do the trick.

Try #2

This should do the trick.

```
USERNAME="Tom"
PASSWORD="abc123"
LIST="USERNAME PASSWORD"
FILE="config.conf"
for item in $LIST; do
    eval "sed -i \"s/\$PLACEHOLDER_$item/\$$item/g\" $FILE"
done
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to make this generic for any variable after $PLACEHOLDER_